# AdMob Plugin Pro Test Ads Work, Live Ads Does Not on Ionic App for Android Platform

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-admob

Title says all about the issue. I get the following error onAdFailLoad for both banner and interstitial ads

```
data.error: 0
data.reason: Internal error
```

I have tried to remove and add the Android platform, tried to uninstall and install the plugin, still does not work. But it works fine on the iOS platform.

Not sure if it matters but the differences when I was developing both apps is that on Android I used test unit ads from google during development which worked, but when I switched to live ad units no ads came up, but I didn't use test unit ads on iOS.

Admob Plugin Pro's github - [Admob Plugin Link](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro)

Comment: Have you tried with [this cordova admob plugin](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova)? There is good [ionic admob documentation here](https://github.com/appfeel/admob-google-cordova/wiki/Angular.js,-Ionic-apps)

Comment: I wanted to use it at some point but then I checked and found that it had not been updated for at least 2 years.

After clicking through your link now I see that some updates has been done. Thanks for suggesting it though. I may use it sometime in the future.

Comment: Yes, after trying different options, for me is the only one it's working now